# Find Last Entry in Row, then Return Value of Cell in Top Row of That Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that records how many times different people have been to an event, names vertically, dates horizontally, with a 1 in each cell to denote attendance, so that the total can be summed up.

What I want is to automate the process of working out who hasn't attended in a long time, so that it will lookup the right-most (most recent) entry in a row, and return the value of the date, which will be in row 1 of that column, so I can create a column of last attended date to sort data by.

I can't work out how to assemble the formula for this, what would be the best way to do it?

Many thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array formula:

```
{=MAX((B2:D2)*$B$1:$D$1)}
```

This formula would be the one to use for the 2nd row, assuming that the 1st row contains your dates and that dates range from column B-D.

Using the array formula carries out a vector multiplication (item by item) so in case there is a 1 (marking attendance) the date will be considered in the MAX formula an in case the cell is empty it will be effectively a zero. Therefore the MAX is only applied to dates where there is an attendance and the result will be the latest attendance date.

For an array formula to work you will need to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter after entering it into the cell. The brackets {} will then be added automatically. You do not type these yourself.